# Many-record upload to postgres

Tags: python, postgresql

I have a series of .csv files with some data, and I want a Python script to open them all, do some preprocessing, and upload the processed data to my postgres database.

I have it mostly complete, but my upload step isn't working. I'm sure it's something simple that I'm missing, but I just can't find it. I'd appreciate any help you can provide.

Here's the code:

```
import psycopg2
import sys
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join
import csv
import re
import io

try:
    con = db_connect("dbname = '[redacted]' user = '[redacted]' password = '[redacted]' host = '[redacted]'")
except:
    print("Can't connect to database.")
    sys.exit(1)
cur = con.cursor()

upload_file = io.StringIO()

file_list = [f for f in listdir(mypath) if isfile(join(mypath, f))]
for file in file_list:
    id_match = re.search(r'.*-(\d+)\.csv', file)
    if id_match:
        id = id_match.group(1)
        file_name = format(id_match.group())
        with open(mypath+file_name) as fh:
            id_reader = csv.reader(fh)
            next(id_reader, None)   # Skip the header row
            for row in id_reader:
                [stuff goes here to get desired values from file]
                if upload_file.getvalue() != '': upload_file.write('\n')
            upload_file.write('{0}\t{1}\t{2}'.format(id, [val1], [val2]))

print(upload_file.getvalue())   # prints output that looks like I expect it to
          # with thousands of rows that seem to have the right values in the right fields

cur.copy_from(upload_file, '[my_table]', sep='\t', columns=('id', 'col_1', 'col_2'))
con.commit()

if con:
    con.close()
```

This runs without error, but a select query in psql still shows no records in the table. What am I missing?

Edit: I ended up giving up and writing it to a temporary file, and then uploading the file. This worked without any trouble...I'd obviously rather not have the temporary file though, so I'm happy to have suggestions if someone sees the problem.

Comment: The code seems OK. You said your `print` line outputs thousands of rows but you passed `'\t'` as a separator to `copy_from`. Maybe that's the problem?

Comment: I'm reading through a couple dozen files that each have a couple hundred records, so it's a total of a few thousands of rows. This line of the code makes them show up as separate rows in the print statement:

if upload_file.getvalue() != '': upload_file.write('\n')

Comment: Yup, that might be the problem then. Try to change `sep='\t'` to `sep='\n'` in you `copy_from` parameters and see if anything changes in the database.

Comment: `psycopg2.DataError: COPY delimiter cannot be newline or carriage return`

Comment: In that case it might be better to change `upload_file.write('\n')` for `upload_file.write('\t')`

Comment: For what it's worth: if I remove everything about the file handling and just do `upload_file.write('88,55,33')` and `cur.copy_from(upload_file, [table name], sep=',', columns=('id', 'col_1', 'col_2'))` I get the same result: code executes and exits normally, but no new row has been added to the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you write to an `io.StringIO` (or any other file) object, the file pointer remains at the position of the last character written. So, when you do

```python
f = io.StringIO()
f.write('1\t2\t3\n')
s = f.readline()
```

the file pointer stays at the end of the file and `s` contains an empty string.

---

To *read* (not `getvalue`) the contents, you must reposition the file pointer to the beginning, e.g. use [`seek(0)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.IOBase.seek)

```
upload_file.seek(0)
cur.copy_from(upload_file, '[my_table]', columns = ('id', 'col_1', 'col_2'))
```

This allows `copy_from` to read from the beginning and import all the lines in your `upload_file`.

---

Don't forget, that you read and keep all the files in your memory, which might work for a single small import, but may become a problem when doing large imports or multiple imports in parallel.

Comment: `Don't forget, that you read and keep all the files in your memory, which might work for a single small import, but may become a problem when doing large imports or multiple imorts in parallel.` This makes me sad though; the whole reason I was doing it this way was that I thought it'd be the fastest way to upload thousands of records at once. I'll dig around and see if I can find a better suggestion in the archives.

Comment: I don't say it's bad, just something to keep in mind, if memory is a concern. And if it's only a few thousand records, I wouldn't worry too much. If memory is a concern, you might try writing the modified CSV to a pipe, which is then read by `copy_from`, if this is possible.

Comment: Ah, ok. So it's about the definition of large and small -- thousands of records is large if the question is about doing `insert values` statements, but small if the question is "will it be painful to store these in memory for a few seconds during a daily batch update". Thanks so much.